# Wsdl to apex class issue with soap1.2

Tags: webservices, soap, wsdl, wsdl2apex, fuseit

I was using [FindRegistrationService](https://wstest.ahpra.gov.au/pie_int/svc/PractitionerRegistrationSearch/2.0.0/FindRegistrationService.svc?singleWsdl) service to generate apex class from FuseIT SFDC Explorer Wsdl2Apex parser. It is giving me below errors. Is it due to SOAP 1.2 services? Is there any way to generate apex class?

```
Error: Apex Classes were not generated. Original error: 
Port class should already be set for [WSHttpBinding_FindRegistrationPortType]. Check that the order of the elements in the WSDL is types, message, portType, binding, service
You can find additional support details on our website using the Help button. 
FuseIT.G4S.SalesforceConnector.Exceptions.WsdlException: Port class should already be set for [WSHttpBinding_FindRegistrationPortType]. Check that the order of the elements in the WSDL is types, message, portType, binding, service
   at FuseIT.G4S.SalesforceConnector.Admin.Wsdl.WsdlToApex.WsdlToApexClass.ProcessToClasses(ApexClassIncludeOptions includeOptions)
   at FuseIT.G4S.SalesforceConnector.Admin.wsdl.WsdlImport.ProcessWsdlToClasses(Dictionary`2 schemaTnsWithClassName, Dictionary`2 methodsRequiredWithMethodType, ApexClassIncludeOptions includeOptions)
   at FuseIT.S4S.Diagnostics.Controls.WsdlParsing.cd083f822b514521235d2054145fc8314(Object ce8524954248814bae94a3d27cee4ed1d, EventArgs c806ab7163f2730be7037401b646d8167)
   at FuseIT.G4S.SalesforceConnector.Admin.Wsdl.WsdlToApex.WsdlToApexClass.ProcessToClasses(ApexClassIncludeOptions includeOptions)
   at FuseIT.G4S.SalesforceConnector.Admin.wsdl.WsdlImport.ProcessWsdlToClasses(Dictionary`2 schemaTnsWithClassName, Dictionary`2 methodsRequiredWithMethodType, ApexClassIncludeOptions includeOptions)
   at FuseIT.S4S.Diagnostics.Controls.WsdlParsing.cd083f822b514521235d2054145fc8314(Object ce8524954248814bae94a3d27cee4ed1d, EventArgs c806ab7163f2730be7037401b646d8167)
FuseIT.G4S.SalesforceConnector Version=3.11.19074.2. SFDC Version=3.11.19074.2
```

Answer (score 2):

The FuseIT WSDL2Apex tool can handle a WSDL that is combination of SOAP 1.1 (supported) and SOAP 1.2 (unsupported) definitions.

Unfortunately, it is only the SOAP 1.1 elements that are support. It just ignores the SOAP 1.2 parts. This comes down to what the underlying `WebServiceCallout.invoke` method supports.

Please consider voting for [Support for SOAP 1.2](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BroSAAS).

Comment: By any chance is there any work around available by which I can consume that service?

Comment: You could potentially use HTTP POST callouts from Apex to invoke the service. It's largely a manual process. Start with something like SOAP UI to see what the structure should look like.